oauth and manuall authentication in node.js
alright, I have a page where users can register using name, email, and password then log in using email and password, now I also want to authenticate using Google Oauth login, so how will that work will I need to change the user model. I have used JWT previously how can I use oauth in tandem
i don't understand the approach for how to do this.
